# How to get dollar($) sign in grand total in OBIEE 12c?

Tags: business-intelligence, obiee, oracle-bi

Please see the screenshot [Grand_total screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epZRL.png)enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

If you correctly set up the Data Format options for the column in question, then any setting also gets applied to the grand total. So just go to "Column Properties" -> "Data Format" -> "Treat Number As" = Currency and "Currency Symbol" = $

Done.

Comment: I did that and still it didn't show $ sign for the grand total.

Comment: What exact version are you using? Exact. So "12.2.1.4.201020" and not "12c" or "12.2.1.4"

Comment: Oracle Business Intelligence 12.2.1.4.0

Comment: Two things: a) that's not an exact version. b) No idea what you mangled in your analysis because in any 12.2.1.4 version this worked perfectly, it works perfectly at the moment so it must be a problem in the construction. The cringing started when I saw that the columns are all SCREAMING IN UPPER CASE and even user underscores. So the guess is that apart from that there's much more incomnsistencies in the whole build.

Comment: If I use fx = sum(Total) then I shows the $ sign for grand total. But if I remove sum then I will not get the $ sign for grand total

Comment: Why would you remove the aggregation? Again - if the underlying model and construction are correct then you never have to touch anything but the data format.

Comment: If I keep aggregation then I will get incorrect data.

Comment: How is that possible? There must be a very basic and central issue with what you're doing. For the tool there is nothing more basic and banal than what you're trying to do.

Comment: Lets say if I have three purchase date for ID 101 and I want the total by latest purchase date then there will be issue if I do sum(aggregation in fx). If I don't do sum then I will get correct data.

Comment: Not if your model is correct and your measures have the correct aggregation rules in the RPD. If you're doing this in the front-end you're already on the wrong path.